# How can I programmatically chromecast an audio and a video with different URI's together on Android?

Tags: android, chromecast

I have two URI's. One is a video URI and other is an audio URI. I want to club them together and send them to a chromecast receiver. Is it possible? If yes, how can I achieve it?

I am not aware of any solutions yet.

Comment: audio URI is audio for video content?

Comment: The video itself has an audio of its own. The audio URI is a URI of a song, which has to be played with the video. It is basically an exercise video.

Comment: Understood, FYI you can pass only one URI for video os audio. If you wan to change audio track for the video, you should use .m3u8 format for video with different audio track. Which format do you use for video URI?

Comment: I use mp4 currently. There is an option to create MergingMediaSource in ExoPlayer but can't see anything for the CastPlayer.